# texmaker 4.0.1 for OS X Pdf Viewer does not work

Tags: pdf, texmaker, viewers, mac

[image]

With "external viewer" it works fine. But there is a problem with the pdf viewer that it shows the text too wide, there is something wrong with it. What should I do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Document may be large and renders slowly. press view pdf again. There might be also bad errors which might change pdf display. verify with other pdf viewers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the good version of Texmaker. You must use the TexmakerMacosx64.zip package and not the TexmakerMacosxLion.zip one (TexmakerMacosxLion is for pure MacOsx Lion system )

Comment: i had to return back to debian, i installed texmaker there. now my problem is to have INTERNAL VIEWER. https://www.dropbox.com/s/wlkeo5mxyid005t/3.png    how to do that?