# Problem with Texmaker version 4.0.2, scrolling

Tags: texmaker

I was using Texmaker version 4.0.1 as editor on my MacBook Air Moutain Lion 10.8.3 and this morning I downloaded the 4.0.2 version of Texmaker. I have some problem with the scrolling with the trackpad, it is highly non fluid! I would like to reinstall the previous version but I realized that I just threw away the previous one to the trash. Does anyone know where to find the previous version of Texmaker on the web? it seems impossible to me...

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: In the current form your question is likely off topic. I think this issue should be sent to the bug tracker of the developer:  https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/list

Comment: May be use the [right TeXmaker version](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html#macosx) for mac as seen in [other User post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106709/15717)

Answer (score 1):

You could compile the version you like. See the [TeXmaker Source files](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html#source) on its homepage to download and compile your own.

Comment: I don't know how to make it work with this shady links and these files in .tar.bz2...... Could we only find texmaker 4.0.1 for mac on the web ?

Answer (score 0):

If you used the 4.0.1 version, you must have downloaded the corresponding package.
So it should be in the "Download" directory or in the "trash folder". Otherwise, you can use the "Time Machine" macosx tool to retrieve this package.

Note : this question doesn't seem to be related with (La)TeX.